# Context and variable scope in ES6 loops and forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, scope, this, ecmascript-6

In ES5, if I have to refer to the `this` context of parent function in child function I have to store it in a variable and access it inside child function using that variable.

Something like this ...

```
//  variant 1
var self = this;
this.nums.forEach(function (v) {
if (v % 5 === 0)
   self.fives.push(v);
});
```

ECMAScript has arrow functions so I can avoid this:

```
// variant 2
this.nums.forEach((v) => {
 if (v % 5 === 0)
   this.fives.push(v)
})
```

The question that I have is: If I was to declare a variable `temp` inside my `forEach` function above will this pollute my global scope? If so will this have performance issues and variable conflicts?

Something similar happens in for loop ....

```
//variant 3
for(var i =0 ;i.......){
   var temp = "tempvariable";
   //some code here
 }

 console.log(temp);
 //output : tempvariable
```

What is the difference between **variant2** and **variant3** code snippets?

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with the variable scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular functions use execution context to set the value of `this`, meaning that in in most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called, i.e. the value of `this` is set according to the environment in which the function is executed.

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value, instead they use lexical scoping, meaning the value of `this` inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope, i.e. it is set to the `this` value of the enclosing execution context.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as well

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value
>   (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the context object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.
>   ....
>   Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context

The third example posted is just a regular `for` loop, and has very little in common with functions, and can't really be compared to the two first code examples.
`for` loops work the same in ES2015 as they always have, there generally is no special scope in `for` loops for variables, as variables *(defined with `var`)* are function scoped.

However, ES2015 does introduce variables that can are block scoped as wel,  and as a  `for` loop is in fact a block *(`for (what) {block}`)*, those variables can be used, and they are defined with either the `let` keyword, or the `const` keyword for a constant *(that can not be changed)* .

For those that prefer code

```
var o = {
    nums  : [1,2,3,4],
    fn    : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.nums.forEach(function(v) {
            // "this" in this context would be the window,
            // but "self" would be the object "o", hence the common use of this hack
        });

        this.nums.forEach((v) => {
            // "this" in this context, would be the object "o"
            // that happens because the "this-value" in the fn() function,
            // ... is the parent object
            // and the arrow function inherits that this-value
        });

        for (var i=0; i<this.nums.length; i++) {
            // "this" in this context is what it has always been,
            // a for-loop has the same this-value as the surrounding scope
        }
    }
}

o.fn(); // called from global context "window"
```

Comment: So this means that any variable declared inside an  arrow function will be available in scope of enclosed function and viceversa ?

Comment: @damitj07 - oh no, they still have their own scope, just like a regular function, and do not "leak" variables to the parent scope, they only inherit the `this` value from the parent scope, that's the difference.

Comment: @damitj07: The body of an arrow function is just as good as a block